# Placement of "algunas veces" in between pluperfect verbs

Tags: gramática

No sé si es buena composición usar una expresión como *algunas veces* en una frase pluscuamperfecto entre *haber* y el verbo.  Por ejemplo, ¿es la frase *habían alguna vez leído* corecta?

---

I am not sure if it's correct to place expressions like *algunas veces* in between pluperfect tenses like *habían leído*.

Comment: ¿Puedes escribir una frase correcta en lugar de solo un fragmento, por favor? A primera vista no me parece correcta, pero fuera de contexto no es fácil asegurarlo.

Comment: la frase no es correcta porque los verbos en español no se suelen separar como en alemán. En todo caso podrías decir: "habían leido alguna vez", y esto si suena mejor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Algunas veces" es una locución adverbial, funciona como un **adverbio** (sinónimo: "ocasionalmente"). En general, la [regla](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2345223) es : el adverbio que modifica un **tiempo verbal compuesto** (en este caso, pasado pluscuamperfecto) **no** debe colocarse entre el "haber" y el participio.

Según esta regla:

> Incorrecto: Ellos **habían algunas veces leído** las instrucciones
>   Correcto:   Ellos **habían leído algunas veces** las instrucciones

Es verdad que, en la práctica, algunas violaciones de esta regla son frecuentes.

> ¿Has acaso meditado las consecuencias de tu acción?
>
> Sin tu ayuda, habría seguramente perdido la partida.
>
> Cuando llegué, él había apenas empezado la tarea.

Estas formas son tolerables, pero incorrectas - en todos los casos es preferible colocar el adverbio después (o antes)  del verbo compuesto.

Ejemplos:

Este [texto](http://www.marxists.org/espanol/mariateg/1927/ene/10.htm) de [Mariategui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Carlos_Mari%C3%A1tegui) incluye no uno sino dos adverbios:

> Perdí una pierna y me quedé muy delicado. Habría **seguramente ya**
>   curado del todo con una existencia reposada.  Pero ni mi pobreza ni mi
>   inquietud espiritual me lo consienten.

Preferible: "Habría curado ya del todo, seguramente, con una existencia reposada"

Y un párrafo de [Ortega y Gasset](http://www.laeditorialvirtual.com.ar/pages/Ortega_y_Gasset/Ortega_LaRebelionDeLasMasas01.htm):

> Si Luzbel hubiera sido ruso, como Tolstoi, habría **acaso** preferido este último estilo de rebeldía...

Preferible: "... habría preferido acaso... "

Comment: +1. Simplemente añadir que los ejemplos que pones al final, no es solo que sean incorrectos, es que aparte suenan como mínimo *muy raro* y parecen malas traducciones del inglés... Suena muchísimo mejor: `acaso has meditado`, `seguramente habría perdido`, `apenas había empezado`, etc...

Comment: A mí no me suenan _tan_ raro, al menos no siempre. He agregado un par de ejemplos literarios.

Comment: En textos literarios tienes razón que no suena tan mal. Pero bueno, a mí si alguien me hablase así por la calle me parecería un *tipo muy raro* ;)